# How to properly re-run Spring Boot application from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I'm working on Spring-Boot app in Eclipse. If I run the app first time, it starts and installs itself on port 8000. But currently I have to stop the app each time I want to re-run it, otherwise I get the error

> Embedded servlet container failed to start. Port 8000 was already in
>   use.

So I understand it as Eclipse is not able to automatically shutdown the existing instance? Each time this happens I have to use lsof -i:8000 to find process ID of the running app and kill it manually.

But that's not the process which everyone uses, no?

Comment: why would you start a process that's already running? and, if the running one is not up-to-date, why is it still running?

Comment: You just click "terminate" or "terminate and restart" like any other Java application.

Comment: Are you implying you want multiple instances running at once?

Comment: ok, at least I discovered the "terminate and restart" option, thanks. But it does not work - it brings me the same message, so Eclipse obviously does not detect the running application. :/

Comment: > why would you start a process that's already running?

I mean just normal developer work process: Fix code -> Start -> Test -> Fix Code etc. Like when you start an app on mobile device from XCode/AndroidStudio it does not matter if the app is already running - it will be shut down and restarted always. I'd expect the same here.

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel usually, there's a "stop" step in between the test and fix code. keeping processes running once you've already deemed them faulty, is asking for trouble

Comment: No, there is no "stop" step "usually", it is not necessary. Also if Eclipse has lost connection to the started app it is not able to stop it (stop button is disabled - but the app is still runninng).

Answer (score 5):

Use option below:

```
Windows-->Preference-->Run/Debug-->Select "Launching"
```

Then check the last option `Terminate and Relaunch While Launching`.
Apply and Close.

Comment: This is the preferred way since it still maintains use of the main run button

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the **Re-Launch** button as follows:

[image]

*If you have multiple spring-boot projects in single workspace, you could choose which to restart from the dropdown next to the button.*

In case you feel previous instance is running, kill the process(using stop button) and use relaunch button later on.

PS. This feature was released in [some version](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492182) of Eclipse Neon. At the time of writing I'm using **Oxygen**.

Comment: Hmm, found no such button on my eclipse toolbar. Found this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=487554  - need to understand what they are writing there

Comment: @ArnieSchwarzvogel Use JavaEE perspective. Reset the perspective. I'm using Eclipse Java EE edition (Oxygen).

Answer (score -1):

As per the error message, the application is not stopped properly, its runnning in background.
First you need to kill the process, then start application again

**STEPS:**

- **For windows:**

Get task list  `C:\>tasklist` 
now you can see list of Java process, then Kill the process by pid 
 Kill process by Process ID(pid)
 `C:\>Taskkill /PID 26356 /F`

- **For Linux:**

Get task list  `ps -ef grep java` 
now you can see list of Java process, then Kill the process by pid 
`kill -9 <PID>`

Then Start Application either from eclipse or command prompt.

**NOTE:** if you find difficulties in doing this then restart your machine.

Comment: OP was aware of this fact and was looking for a way to have the app gracefully restart without needing to resort to killing the process manually